# contents of fragment is copied to another fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having a problem with RecyclerView and Fragment .I have 4 tabs each tab contains a RecyclerView .
My problem is that i see the same results on different tabs ,looks like the fragments are being copied.

my main activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolBar);
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_pager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabLayout);


    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    fragmentInvite = new InviteFragment();
    attendingFragment = new AttendingFragment();
    notAttendingFragment = new NotAttendingFragment();
    maybeFragment = new MaybeFragment();
    adapter.addFragment(fragmentInvite, "first");
    adapter.addFragment(attendingFragment, "second");
    adapter.addFragment(notAttendingFragment, "third");
    adapter.addFragment(maybeFragment, "fourth");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

my fragment adapter:

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        fragments.add(fragment);
        titles.add(title);
    }

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }
}
```

this is the RecyclerViewer adapter

```
public class rvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<rvAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private static List<Contact> contacts;


    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextViewName;
        public CheckBox mCheckBox;
        public TextView mTextViewNumber;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.mTextViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            this.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_check_box);
            this.mTextViewNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public rvAdapter(List<Contact> contacts) {

        this.contacts = contacts;

        Log.d("TAG","constructor "+contacts.size());
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        CustomViewHolder vh = new CustomViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder,int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        String name = contacts.get(position).getName();
        String number = contacts.get(position).getPhone_number();
        //Boolean status = contacts.get(position).isSelected();
        holder.mTextViewName.setText(name);
        holder.mTextViewNumber.setText(number);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }


}
```

first fragment:

```
public class InviteFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView rv_invite;
    private Button btn_done;
    private List<String> numbers;
    private AlertDialog ratingDialog;
    private String message;
    public  ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    private rvAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_invite, container, false);

        numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        //find done button
        btn_done = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_done);
        //find listview
        rv_invite = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_invite);
        //get contacts list

        setContacts(numbers);
        //sorting the contact list
        Collections.sort(contacts);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        //mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rv_invite.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new rvAdapter(contacts);

        rv_invite.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return view;
    }
```

second fragment:

```
public class AttendingFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button btn_resend;
    private RecyclerView attending;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private rvAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attending, container, false);

        attending = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.attending_recycler_view);


        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        attending.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new rvAdapter(MainActivity.attending);
        attending.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return  v;
    }
```

third fragment:

```
public class NotAttendingFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView rv_not_attending;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_not_attending, container, false);

        rv_not_attending = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.not_attending_recycler_view);


        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        rv_not_attending.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new rvAdapter(MainActivity.not_attending);
        rv_not_attending.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        return  v;
    }
```

fourth fragment:

```
public class MaybeFragment extends Fragment {


    private List<Boolean> status;
    private RecyclerView rv_maybe;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private rvAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maybe, container, false);
        rv_maybe = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.maybe_recycler_view);


        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        rv_maybe.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new rvAdapter(MainActivity.maybe);

        rv_maybe.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: The question description is very ambiguous. Try reformulating it. Also, provide code regarding the recyclerview(s). There is no code in the current post.

Comment: try to clear what's your question exactly is

Comment: I see the same fragment on different tabs.I have edited question. thank you

Comment: include de code from the fragments where you populate or load de recycler adapter

Comment: include fragments code thanks @TinMegali

Comment: I believe the problem is in your MainActivity, probably were you set the values from your arrays. When you set your values from your fragments by the call 'mAdapter = new rvAdapter(MainActivity.not_attending);' . I don't know for sure because you didn't post those values in your MainActivity code. Please do.

Comment: it's just a list of object with name and phone number

Comment: I have tried to pass it through a bundle and the same result.

Comment: @Maximtoyberman I created a answer with some ideas. Follow the instructions and let me know in the comments. I'll try to help you with this.

Comment: ﹕ >>> AdapterValue: [Contact{name='max', phone_number='+525942787'}]
 >>> MainActvity value :[Contact{name='max', phone_number='+525942787'}] @TinMegali

Comment: Damn't ... I will reproduce your scenario here.

Comment: Help me here. Send me a link with the code on a git account. I'll clone it and dig in with you.

Comment: Thank you ! https://github.com/MaxToyberman/Contacts.git

Comment: I think the problem is with my adapter because when i comment out the line attending.setAdapter(mAdapter); the tabs are not overriding each other @TinMegali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the adapter

```
@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

    CustomViewHolder vh = new CustomViewHolder(v);

    return vh;
}
```

should be :

```
@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(ctx)
            .inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

    CustomViewHolder vh = new CustomViewHolder(v);

    return vh;
}
```

passing the context from the fragment solved the problem.
when i used parent.getContext() my details were overwritten on the other fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you Arrays are set correctly in your MainActivity, try to change the part where you fetch these values in your fragments.

Change

```
 mAdapter = new rvAdapter(MainActivity.maybe);
```

To

```
 mAdapter = new rvAdapter( ((MainActivity.class)getActivity() ).maybe );
```

If that change didn't do the trick, proceed with the following instruction an comment the results. Turn your `contacts` field in the adapter public and insert these lines inside your changed frag code for tests. Post the logs in the comments.

```
Log.i( this.getClass().getSimpleName(), ">>> AdapterValue: " + mAdapter.contacts );
Log.i( "MainActivity", ">>> MainActvity value :" + ((MainActivity.class)getActivity()).maybe );
```